# Phone Call within Table Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, ibaction

Im writing an app where someone adds a contact to the app, giving their name, number and photo. Then this information is displayed in a table, with each individual contact on a different cell and when the user presses on the cell it will call the number that was typed in for the contact. I have put in a large button on each of the cells for the user to press. This is the code

**PictureListMainTable.m**

```
#import "PictureListMainTable.h"
#import "PictureListDetail.h"
#import "CoreDataHelper.h"
#import "Pictures.h"

@implementation PictureListMainTable

@synthesize managedObjectContext, pictureListData, callButton;

//  When the view reappears, read new data for table
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //  Repopulate the array with new table data
    [self readDataForTable];
}

//  Grab data for table - this will be used whenever the list appears or reappears after an add/edit
- (void)readDataForTable
{
    //  Grab the data
    pictureListData = [CoreDataHelper getObjectsForEntity:@"Pictures" withSortKey:@"title" andSortAscending:YES andContext:managedObjectContext];

    //  Force table refresh
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Actions

//  Button to log out of app (dismiss the modal view!)
- (IBAction)logoutButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Segue methods

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //  Get a reference to our detail view
    PictureListDetail *pld = (PictureListDetail *)[segue destinationViewController];

    //  Pass the managed object context to the destination view controller
    pld.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;

    //  If we are editing a picture we need to pass some stuff, so check the segue title first
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditPicture"])
    {
        //  Get the row we selected to view
        NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];

        //  Pass the picture object from the table that we want to view
        pld.currentPicture = [pictureListData objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

//  Return the number of sections in the table
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

//  Return the number of rows in the section (the amount of items in our array)
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [pictureListData count];
}



//  Create / reuse a table cell and configure it for display
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";





    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    // Get the core data object we need to use to populate this table cell
    Pictures *currentCell = [pictureListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //  Fill in the cell contents
    cell.textLabel.text = [currentCell title];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [currentCell desc];

    int number;


    number = [currentCell desc];

        -(IBAction)MakePhoneCall:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:",number]];
}






    //  If a picture exists then use it
    if ([currentCell smallPicture])
    {
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentCell smallPicture]];
    }
    else{


    }



    return cell;

}

//  Swipe to delete has been used.  Remove the table item
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //  Get a reference to the table item in our data array
        Pictures *itemToDelete = [self.pictureListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //  Delete the item in Core Data
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:itemToDelete];

        //  Remove the item from our array
        [pictureListData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //  Commit the deletion in core data
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
            NSLog(@"Failed to delete picture item with error: %@", [error domain]);

        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}


-(IBAction)MakePhoneCall:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:",number]];
}

@end
```

**PictureListMainTable.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PictureListMainTable : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pictureListData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *callButton;




-(IBAction)MakePhoneCall:(id)sender;

- (void)readDataForTable;

@end
```

Where should I place the IBaction and why isint it working at the moment where it is and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you could take to achieve this. But firstly, I don't understand what you are doing at the bottom of `-tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. It's as if you are trying to define your IBAction method inside this method. You also have it defined at the bottom of the implementation, but in that method the `number` variable is not in scope.

Anyway, you should subclass the `UITableViewCell`. In the implementation for the subclass, you should define the IBAction method and hook it up in interface builder, or otherwise.

When the button is tapped, you should hand the number for the selected cell back to the PictureListMainTable view controller, in order for that view controller to process it (i.e. call the number). You can do this in two ways:

**1) the delegate method**

Create a protocol, defined in the header file for your subclass of UITableViewCell. And make the main view controller conform to this protocol. Set the cell's delegate to the main view controller. In the implementation of the cell subclass, call this delegate method. For example:

**the header file for the UITableViewCell subclass "PictureListMainTableCell.h"**

```
@protocol PictureListMainTableCellDelegate;

@interface PictureListMainTableCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *telephoneNumber;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PictureListMainTableCellDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol PictureListMainTableCellDelegate
-(void)pictureListMainTableCell:(PictureListMainTableCell *)cell wantsToCallNumber:(NSString *)number;
@end
```

**the implementation file "PictureListMainTableCell.m"**

```
#import "PictureListMainTableCell.h"

@implementation PictureListMainTableCell

-(IBAction)MakePhoneCall:(id)sender
{
    //send the delegate the number to call.
    [self.delegate pictureListMainTableCell:self wantsToCallNumber:self.telephoneNumber];
}

@end
```

Above, in the MakePhoneCall method, we call `-pictureListMainTableCell:wantsToCallNumber:` on the delegate. In this case, the delegate is your main view controller. We will set this below.

Setting the cell's delegate: In your main view controller file (PictureListMainTable.m), in the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, set the delegate on the cell to `self`. e.g.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // get the cell...
    PictureListMainTableCell *cell = // dequeue the cell

    // do some other setting up...

    // set the delegate on the cell
    cell.delegate = self;

    // set the telephoneNumber variable on the cell, for example...
    cell.telephoneNumber = [currentCell desc];

    return cell;
}
```

Now you need to make sure `self` implements the delegate method. So still in PictureListMainTable.m, you need to define the method as follows:

```
#pragma mark - PictureListMainTableCellDelegate methods
-(void)pictureListMainTableCell:(PictureListMainTableCell *)cell wantsToCallNumber:(NSString *)number
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", number];
    NSLog(@"calling telephone number [%@]", number);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
}
```

You should also specify that the PictureListMainTable class conforms to your new protocol, as well as the UITableViewDataSource protocol. Add a private category on PictureListMainTable as follows (at the top of the implementation file, after the imports, before `@implementation`):

```
@interface PictureListMainTable () <UITableViewDataSource, PictureListMainTableCellDelegate>
@end
```

(this extends the PictureListMainTable interface. It only extends it to specify privately that it conforms to these protocols.)

**2) the NSNotification method**

While I was typing out the above explanation, I decided it's my preferred way of doing things, so I would recommend doing it like that. There is the option of posting an NSNotification form your cell subclass, and observing for this notification from your main view controller. Just look into NSNotificationCenter, the following methods:
`–postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` (send the number in userInfo dictionary). Listen for it using `–addObserver:selector:name:object:`.

But like I said, option 1 is better, in my opinion.

Let me know if anything is unclear, good luck :)

**EDIT:** I really recommend reading this blog post to understand delegation: http://alexefish.com/post/15966868557/understanding-and-creating-delegates-in-objective-c

Comment: Create the two files "PictureListMainTableCell.h" and "PictureListMainTableCell.m" as described above (the line `@interface PictureListMainTableCell : UITableViewCell` means that you're defining PictureListMainTableCell as a subclass of UITableViewCell). I assume you've added a prototype cell in Interface Builder? So select the cell and go to the "identity inspector" in the right-hand pane (it's the third 'tab' along). In the "Class" text field, change it from UITableViewCell to "PictureListMainTableCell". Make the other code changes as described above and you should be on the right track.

Comment: Thanks again, im getting some errors though about the  `@implementation PictureListMainTable <UITableViewDataSource, PictureListMainTableCellDelegate>`

Comment: Thanks so much. Im still getting to warnings though. The first is at the top at the `@implementation PictureListMainTable` it says incomplete implementation. The second is at the bottom by the method for the phone call it is Data argument not used by format string, any ideas on this?

Comment: sorry, see my updated answer. It should be `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", number]`. incomplete implementation is weird, it suggests you haven't implemented the delegate method. Did you implement `-(void)pictureListMainTableCell:(PictureListMainTableCell *)cell wantsToCallNumber:(NSString *)number` in "PictureListMainTableCell.m"?

Comment: no just realised i didt, i just did no it looks like this: `#import "PictureListMainTableCell.h"

@implementation PictureListMainTableCell

-(void)pictureListMainTableCell:(PictureListMainTableCell *)cell wantsToCallNumber:(NSString *)number;


-(IBAction)MakePhoneCall:(id)sender
{
    //send the delegate the number to call.
    [self.delegate pictureListMainTableCell:self wantsToCallNumber:self.telephoneNumber];
}


@end` however now i get the error "expected method body"?

Comment: Sorry it's late... I meant you need to implement it in "PictureListMainTable.m" as described in my original answer. You need to implement the method, (i.e. add some functionality between `{` and `}`. See `#pragma mark - PictureListMainTableCellDelegate methods` in my original answer. This should go in "PictureListMainTable.m".

Comment: oh yeh sorry, well ive placed the PictureListMainTableCellDelegate methods at the bottom right before `@end` and i have written exactly what you have written but I still get the warnings, am I placing the method in the wrong area maybe?

Comment: have you added `#import "PictureListMainTableCell.h"` to the top of PictureListMainTable.m?

Comment: I went and looked at the proper error and it said Method definition for 'MakePhoneCall:' not found in PictureListMainTable.m

Comment: not sure what's gone wrong. I've create a project on github here: https://github.com/sdods3782/PhoneTableTest. It's exactly what I wrote above, I ran it and it worked fine. Feel free to have a look. If you get to the bottom of it, it would be interesting to hear what the problem was.

Comment: thanks so much ill take a look and try to work out the issue.

Comment: do you have the MakePhoneCall method defined in the header file PictureListMainTable.h? If so, get rid of it. Also, did you clean up `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` because it was erroneous in your original post (not sure if it was a copy/paste error, but you can't define MakePhoneCall inside another method body).

Comment: Thanks Ive worked out the issue, I deleted `int number; number = [currentCell desc];` and the warning went, Thanks for your help, I am now going to test it out on my iphone.

Comment: Is there anyway you can simulate the call?

Comment: not that I know of in the simulator. but put a break point in the `-pictureListMainTableCell:wantsToCallNumber:` method to verify that it is being called. (fyi, add a break point by clicking in the gutter to the left of the code in the method body. remove it by dragging it into the code, let go and it goes up in a cloud of smoke!)

Comment: yes, that's right. so i assume you have it compiling without warnings now?

Comment: yeh I put the break point `-(void)pictureListMainTableCell:(PictureListMainTableCell *)cell wantsToCallNumber:(NSString *)number
{`  **HERE**
    `NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", number];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
}
`Nothing comes up though

Comment: so you tap the "call" button and it doesn't stop on the break point? that's weird. Have you linked up the IBAction method to the button in Interface Builder? To do this, show the cell and the button in the view controller view hierarchy tree, hold down ctrl key, click and drag from the button to the cell, then let go. It will pop up a black box saying "Sent events" and the name of your IBAction method "MakePhoneCall". If you've already done that, then you'll need to debug your app, try putting a break point in the MakePhoneCall method. It should definitely get called when you tap the button.

Comment: when I put it there and i connect the button to MakePhoneCall to touch down and I add the break point, nothing happens

Comment: The breakpoint worked this time however the button is only there for one cell

Comment: try using 'touch up inside' it shouldn't make a difference, but that's more common to use, because usually a user can cancel a tap by moving of the button with the finger down. did you try my sample project on github? i tested it and it works fine. Can you confirm that the prototype cell in Interface Builder is definitely of type PictureListMainTableCell? (look in identity inspector.)

Comment: okk ive changed it yes i can confirm that, how do I find out the number which the app wwas going to call?

Comment: I looked at your source and I cant find a difference

Comment: you could add `NSLog(@"calling telephone number [%@]", number);` in `pictureListMainTableCell:wantsToCallNumber:` method (see updated original answer). Or you could set the breakpoint and look at what number was passed into the method. While stopped on a breakpoint, you can print out values of variables using the `po` command in the lldb window.

Comment: have you set a value to the telephoneNumber property on the cell? See `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` where I set `cell.telephoneNumber = [currentCell desc];`

Comment: glad i could help. and thanks for the tick! please up-vote any of my comments that you found particularly helpful :)